# RabbitMQ: Message duplication in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: c#, kubernetes, rabbitmq, microservices, .net-7.0

we have more than 100 microservices consume messages from Rabbitmq, but due to network issues, the connection is lost and recovered(re-established) between services and Rabbitmq , then messages redelivered, and services process these messages again which can be fatal to us.

I read about "RabbitMQ Message Deduplication Plugin" but is designed to prevent publishers from publishing duplicate messages.
what is the recommended practice to handle this situation with minimum cost?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is impossible to guarantee that the messages will be processed exactly once (no messaging infrastructure in a system where there's a nonzero chance of either network or compute failure can make this general guarantee): you can guarantee at-most-once (by not redelivering) or at-least-once (by redelivering).

It is possible (at least in many applications) to process messages in an "effectively once" manner by combining at-least-once delivery (redelivering messages until acknowledged as successfully processed) with idempotent processing: processing the same message *n*>1 times has the same observable effect as processing it only once (in general, when messaging infrastructure makes claims about exactly-once, they mean "effectively once").  In some sense, this is changing the way the service processes messages so that it can't be fatal.

How (or even if) you can accomplish this is dependent on the processing: the general requirement is that your service has to be able to keep enough of its own state to record that it has processed a given message and be able to record that processing atomically with the processing (so that either the message gets processed and recorded as processed or it gets neither processed nor recorded as processed: if it's possible for the message to be recorded as processed and not processed, you've put in the effort to reimplement at-most-once and *vice versa* reimplemented at-least-once).  If the processing entails only updating a relational database, for instance, you could record that the message was processed in the same database transaction as the actual updates for processing.

Comment: I don't often do that, but I cannot resist to tell how much I enjoyed reading this answer, very well worded! :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per [blog of rabbitmq](https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2020/06/cluster-sizing-and-other-considerations/#how-does-message-size-affect-sizing) that is written by Jack Vanlightly, you can use more quorum queues or mirrored queues do address multiple brokers or microservices.

Thus, adding more redundancy or replica of the deployment will reduce throughput to spread out messaging loads. This will also create vertical upgrade to your nodes and if available, you may look to either CPU or memory intensive instances to address the needs of your deployment.